# how to consider two words as single word with stanfordNLP

Tags: nlp

if I type the sentence like "I like chicken biryani"
in the above, I need to make chicken biryani as a single word.
how to achieve with Stanford NLP or with any approach

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to explain what you have tried to solve the problem and avoid asking generic questions. You will run the risk of your question getting down voted. Having said that, here are two things you can do.

1. Use dependency parser. It will chunk the entities for you.
2. Use POS tagger and chunk all the noun tags and use it as single word.

Here is a link where you can try dependency parser [Stanford dependency parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)